# string comparison in ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm trying to make an ssreflect [OrdType](https://www.lri.fr/%7Ehivert/Coq-Combi/Combi.Basic.ordtype.html) out of a custom type which involves strings. I assume that there is some inbuilt order type for strings in ssreflect, but I can't find it anywhere. I see one in Coq's standard library, but I can't figure out if the definition transfers to the ssreflect library. I'd much rather use ssreflect than the Coq standard library.  Could someone point me where to look please?
Thanks.

Comment: AFAIR, [extructures](https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures) has its own ordType and an instance for strtings. However, these days there is a number of types with order/lattice structures in Mathcomp: https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/ssreflect/order.v. Although, it does have an instance for strings.

Comment: * sorry, I made a typo: does *not* have an instance for strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately `OrdType` is not the order that has been integrated to [mathcomp/ssreflect package](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/ssreflect/order.v) in the end (Coq-Combi preceeds this integration), but it follows the same scheme.
Which order do you want? Lexicogrphic? Prefix? Suffix?

- If you want to use lexicographic order with the standardized order in mathcomp/ssreflect, I suggest you use the isomorphism between `String` and `list ascii` and the lexical ordering on the latter to define a total order on string (you need to provide a `orderType` canonical structure for `ascii`).
- If you want a prefix order, you can prove `Strings.prefix` function is a partial order.